# AspectJ compatibility

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

We are using an external library that has been compile-time weaved with AspectJ 1.9.6. We would like to use Java 17 and thus need at least AspectJ 1.9.8 to compile-time weave our own code. During runtime we have a shared classpath (WEB-INF/lib) for both our classes and the external library. Is it save to provide an AspectJ Runtime Version 1.9.8 here? Can we even go further and use the latest version of the runtime (which is then also used to compile-time weave our code) --> 1.9.9.1?

Basically: Is the compile-time weaved code of our external dependency compatible with those higher runtimes?

(I am aware of the statements noted at: https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/compatibility.html)

Comment: That's just a patch version change. It should be safe to use the latest `1.9.x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please just use the latest AspectJ version, as of today 1.9.9.1, see

https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/blob/master/docs/release/JavaVersionCompatibility.adoc

*Semi off topic: Actually, I could release AspectJ 1.9.19 (in the future, the minor-minor will mirror the latest supported Java version) anytime, if it was not for some [unfixed Eclipse Java compiler bugs concerning Java 19 preview features](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/issues/184#issuecomment-1272254940), which I would like to see fixed upstream before releasing the next AspectJ version. But you do not need Java 19 language features, so you are fine with 1.9.9.1.*

Comment: Just to double check and it has not been over-read... The 1.9.9.1 runtime is able to cope with the 1.9.6 compile-time weaved code?

Comment: Yes, AspectJ versions are always backwards compatible.